# Find the intersection of ArrayList elements inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, interview-questions

So the structure is `{{Dog,Cat,Human},{Human,Dog,Whale,rabbit,Cow},{Monkey,Human,Dog}}`.

Output should be: `Dog,Human`.

I have to find the intersection of `ArrayList` elements (Strings, for now. Could be integers as well) inside the bigger `ArrayList`. Previously, I have seen codes of finding the intersection of separate `ArrayLists`, but not sure how I could do it inside the same `ArrayList`.

For separate `ArrayLists` a code like the following works. But how do I make it work for multiple `ArrayLists` inside one `ArrayList`? I was asked this in an interview. Worked for separate lists, but when the interviewer asked this, I couldn't code it out for the same `ArrayList`.

```
public class Test {

    public <String> List<String> intersection(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String t: list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Human"));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Human", "Dog", "Whale", "rabbit", "Cow"));

        System.out.println(new Test().intersection(list1, list2));

    }
}
```

This produces correct output for two separate `ArrayLists`.

Comment: As it appears, if each element of a `List` is a `List` itself, you can call `intersection` in a loop like you might calculate the sum of elements in a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Also, your question looks to be about code not yet written, and this site is not for coding advice in general. You might want to try StackOverflow.

Comment: Plus, are you sure you wanted `intersection`'s type parameter to be named `String`?

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure the idea behind the question is an application of Mathematical Induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approaching programming interview questions

One of the most important things during programming interviews is clarifying the problem.
If the task is intersection of *lists* as opposed to *sets*,
an important question is how to handle duplicate values.

For example, the current implementation is buggy.
The `intersection` method will return `a,a,a` for the input `a,a,a` and `a,a`, but it will give `a,a` for the input `a,a` and `a,a,a`.
The logical assumption would be that it should always return `a,a` regardless of the order of parameters.
Then again, you should not just assume things,
you should ask for the expected behavior,
or at least state your assumptions loud and clear.

And if there can be no duplicates in the inputs,
then why aren't they sets instead of lists?

Why is `ArrayList` specified instead of just `List`?
`ArrayList` is a specific implementation,
when `List` is the general concept.

#### Generic type tokens

`String`, the name of a common class in the JDK,
and written in `PascalCase`,
is a terrible choice for a generic type token in this code:

> ```
> public <String> List<String> intersection(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
>     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
>
>     for (String t: list1) {
>         if(list2.contains(t)) {
>             list.add(t);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return list;
> }
> ```

It should have been written like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T t : list1) {
        if (list2.contains(t)) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

#### Intersection of many lists

> But how do I make it work for multiple `ArrayLists` inside one `ArrayList`?

I'm not sure I get what's blocking you.
Perhaps you mean, instead of the intersection of 2 lists,
how to intersect more than 2?

In that case,
that's an interesting question to discuss about,
and consider different alternatives,
starting from simple (brute force) techniques,
and then trying to improve.

Simple solution: if you have `n` lists, you could intersect the first 2,
then intersect the result with the 3rd,
then intersect the result with the 4th,
and so on, until the last.
The final result will be the intersection of all the lists,
reachable in `n - 1` steps.

Is it possible to do better?

- Hint 1: consider the concept of divide and conquer.
- Hint 2: how does merge sort work?